# My Vue root file/component is not showing up in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm following this [simple Crud tutorial for Vue + Laravel](https://www.positronx.io/create-laravel-vue-js-crud-single-page-application/) and everything in Laravel part seems fine (from creating controllers & models) seems fine but I can't make vue show up in Laravel welcome blade. Here's my code:

app.js file

```
 require('./bootstrap');
 window.Vue = require('vue'); 
 import App from './App.vue';
 import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
 import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
 import axios from 'axios';
 import { routes } from './routes';
 
 Vue.use(VueRouter);
 Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
  
 const router = new VueRouter({
     mode: 'history',
     routes: routes
    });
    
    
 const app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     router: router,
     render: h => h(App),
     });
```

App.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="container"> 
        <h2>Vue app</h2>
     
        <router-view> </router-view>
    </div>
</template>
 
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

and this is the welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>
        
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div id="app"> </div>
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <h2>The welcome blade</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

edit: answer added below, basically followed another [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqkzl9TPW5E)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Secondly, you may need a router view element inside the div with id app. I can't say for sure since I don't know your routes. If the change above doesn't solve the problem, add router view like

```
<div id="app">
    <router-view />
</div>
```

UPDATE

Another thing to try. Remove these lines

```
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
```

because you have axios on bootstrap.js file.

And make sure there is no error message on the console.

Comment: mix('js/app.js') is the correct thing to use if you use versioning (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting)

Comment: Yes, but there is nothing about versioning in the question.

Comment: I tried both adding a component and changing the script src but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: I add anothet possible solution to my answer.

Comment: thank you for your time but it must have been something in my end, I redid the installation based in another tutorial and it's working fine now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code after `composer require laravel/ui` and `php artisan ui vue` I see small change that may affect the execution of code.
Originally the Laravel setup creates `window.Vue = require('vue').default;`, but your code has `window.Vue = require('vue')`

Comment: I copied it from the tutorial I linked in the post but I tried as you said and still no changes

Answer (score 0):

So it must have been something wrong with my installation process because I followed another tutorial and now it's working [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqkzl9TPW5E)